# Drupal insert query with uploaded CSV file

Tags: 7, database

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => float 1110
      'description' => string 'Culture de céréales (à l'exception du riz), de légumineuses et de graines oléagineuses' (length=86)
      'field2' => float 11
      'field3' => float 26.631
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => float 1120
      'description' => string 'Culture du riz' (length=14)
      'field2' => float 11
      'field3' => float 7.556
```

With this array what is the correct process for the string "description" to avoid SQL error when data is added with `db_insert` ?

I use this code for multiple insert :

```
$query = db_insert('table')->fields(array('id', 'description', 'field2', 'field3'));

foreach ($sql_query as $record) {
     $query->values($record);
}

$query->execute();

// $sql_query is the array described above.
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: In backend (rapport tab) : PDOException : in _mymodule_addrow() line 87 ... In fontend I have the default error page of Drupal without any explanation.

Comment: Check your logs and watchdog, the real error message is in there. We need to know what it says

Comment: In the log it's only displayed: "PDOException : in _mymodule_addrow() line 87" + file path but without details... :'(

Comment: could it be from the "à l'exception"  apostrophe?

Comment: Could you make a title here bit more unique and informative? We have hundreds (if not thousands) questions about insert queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data come form a file where string were not convert to utf8 at the opening thus the Drupal 7 parsing function for database query couldn't convert string to avoid SQL error.

Sorry but I didn't think that the problem could be as much upstream...